# Memory consumption of a concurrent data structure in C

Tags: c, memory, concurrency

I would like to know how much memory a given data structure is consuming. So suppose I have a concurrent linked list. I would like to know how big the list is. I have a few options: `malloc_hooks`, which I do not think is thread-safe, and `getrusage`'s `ru_maxrss`, but I don't really know what that gives me (how much memory the whole process consumed during its execution?). I would like to know if someone has actually measured memory consumption in this way. Is there a tool to do this? How does `massif` fare?

Comment: does anyone know about http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an idea of how many bytes it actually costs to `malloc` some structure, like a linked list node, make an isolated test case(non-concurrent!) which allocates thousands of them, and look at the delta values in the program's memory usage. There are various ways to do that. If your library has a `mallinfo` structure, like the GNU C Library found on GNU/Linux systems, you can look at the statistics before and after. Another way is to trace the program's system calls to watch its pattern of allocating from the OS. If, say, we allocate 10,000,000 list nodes, and the program performs a `sbrk()` call about 39,000 times, increasing the size of the process by 8192 bytes in each call, then that means that a list node takes up 32 bytes, overhead and all.

Keeping in mind that allocating thousands of objects of the same size in a single thread does not realistically represent the actual memory usage in a realistic program, which includes fragmentation.

If you want to allocate small structures and come close to not wasting a byte (or not causing any waste that you don't know about and control), and to control fragmentation, then allocate large arrays of the objects from `malloc` (or your system allocator of choice) and break them up yourself. There is still unknown overhead in the `malloc` but it is divided over a large number of objects, making it negligible.

Or, generally, write your own allocator whose behavior and overheads you understand in detail, and which itself takes big chunks from the system.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually speaking you need to know the number of items you are working with.  Then you need to know the size of each different data type used in your data structure. You also will have to take into account the size of pointers or anything that is somewhat using some sort of memory.

Then you can come up with a formula that looks like the following:

Consumption= N  *(sizeof(data types) ).

So in other words you want  to make sure you add any data type together (the data type's size) and multiply it by the number of items.